# How to make redirection to another site in OCstore admin?

Tags: redirect, opencart

How to make redirection to another site in OCstore admin?

The point is this: I made a customer site. he had a site on ocstore, but it was not beautiful and inconvenient. I developed a new one, and the customer asks me to delete the old site. all I have is a login and password from the ocstore admin. no hosting, no domain. well, I came to the conclusion to put redirects from the old site to the new one. gpt advised to do it through .htaccess. it can only be edited using ftp, as I understand, but there is no ftp in opencart from version 3. what should I do?

I'll tell you right away, I didn't immediately run here, I tried to make a modifier, but it doesn't work(

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Redirect All Pages to Miko-Astana</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Your Name</author>
    <link>https://yourwebsite.com</link>
    <code>redirect_all_pages_to_miko_astana</code>
    <file path="catalog/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function index() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                header('Location: https://miko-astana.kz');
                exit();
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what changed, I deleted all the modifiers that were on the site, created a new modifier with the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Redirect All Pages to New Website</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Your Name</author>
    <link>https://yourwebsite.com</link>
    <code>redirect_all_pages_to_new_website</code>
    <file path="catalog/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function index() {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                header('Location: https://miko-astana.kz');
                exit();
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

and the page started redirecting. maybe someone will be in a similar situation, so I won't delete the question, but if someone wants to make a report, it's up to you).